# Principal Components Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca

We want to perform regression using PCR (Principal Components Regression) and we have two of our variables as X1 and X2. The correlation between X1 and the outcome variable Y
is 0 and the correlation between X2 and Y is 0.9. Should we conclude X2 will receive more
weight in the the 1rst factor loading of PCR regression? Why or why not?
Would the answer change in the case of performing a regression using PLS (Partial Least Squares)?

Thanks a lot for your view on this problem!

Comment: Is this a study exercise? If so, please add the self-study tag, and describe what you've tried so far and where exactly you're stuck